# Choose 1 out of 5 select menus and disable the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 5 select menus, if one of the options in any select menu is chosen, on all other select menus I would like to:

- .prop required to false
- .prop disabled to true
- .css("background-color","#e8e8e8");

I have wrote the code for the first select menu and this works fine, my question is how can I write this tidly for all 5 select menus to eradicate any unnecessary lines of code.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
        <li id="li_13" >
        <label class="description" for="element_13">A</label>
        <div>
        <select id="element_13" name="element_13" required="required"> 
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

        </select>
        </li>       

        <li id="li_14" >
        <label class="description" for="element_14">B</label>
        <div>
        <select id="element_14" name="element_14" required="required"> 
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

        </select>
        </li>       

        <li id="li_15" >
        <label class="description" for="element_15">C</label>
        <div>
        <select id="element_15" name="element_15" required="required"> 
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

        </select>
        </li>       

        <li id="li_16" >
        <label class="description" for="element_16">D</label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_16" name="element_16" required="required"> 
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
        </li>       

        <li id="li_17" >
        <label class="description" for="element_17">E</label>
        <div>
        <select id="element_17" name="element_17" required="required"> 
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

        </select>
        </li>       

        <li id="li_18" >
        <label class="description" for="element_18">F</label>
        <div>
        <select id="element_18" name="element_18" required="required"> 
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
       $('#element_13').change(function(){

        if ($(this).val().length != 0){

                    $('#element_14').prop('required', false);
                    $('#element_15').prop('required', false);
                    $('#element_16').prop('required', false);
                    $('#element_17').prop('required', false);
                    $('#element_18').prop('required', false);

                    $('#element_14').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#element_15').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#element_16').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#element_17').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#element_18').prop('disabled', true);

                    $('#li_14').css("background-color","#993333");
                    $('#li_15').css("background-color","#993333");
                    $('#li_16').css("background-color","#993333");
                    $('#li_17').css("background-color","#993333");
                    $('#li_18').css("background-color","#993333");
            }
            else{               
                    $('#element_14').prop('required', true);
                    $('#element_15').prop('required', true);
                    $('#element_16').prop('required', true);
                    $('#element_17').prop('required', true);
                    $('#element_18').prop('required', true);

                    $('#element_14').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#element_15').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#element_16').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#element_17').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#element_18').prop('disabled', false);

                    $('#li_14').css("background-color","#e8e8e8");
                    $('#li_15').css("background-color","#e8e8e8");
                    $('#li_16').css("background-color","#e8e8e8");
                    $('#li_17').css("background-color","#e8e8e8");
                    $('#li_18').css("background-color","#e8e8e8");
            }
        });
```

**UPDATED FROM ANSWER USING CLASS AS SELECTOR (ALSO BETTER WITH SHOW/HIDE):**

```
        $(".complaint").on("change", function() {
            if ($(this).val().length != 0){
            $(".complaint").not(this)
              .prop("required", false)
              .prop("disabled", true)
              .closest("li").hide();
             }
        else{
            $(".complaint").not(this)
              .prop("required", true)
              .prop("disabled", false)
              .closest("li").show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $("select").not(this)
      .prop({ required : false, disabled : true })
      .closest("li").css("background-color", "#e8e8e8");
});
```

In order to differentiate your `<select>` elements from other `<select>` elements on the page you may set common class name to them and use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of tag selector, as in example.

Comment: thanks, if i have other selects in the form should i give these a class and use the class as the selector?

Comment: @Codded Yes, that would be preferable.

Comment: In this method what if the user wants to select a different one, they would select the blank select and all should become enabled again etc --- like in my example. --- also this - $("select").on("change", function() { would be all selects on form, should i differentiate with $(".class").on("change", function() {

Comment: updated the question with the working solution that I am using, all is working great. Thanks

Comment: @Codded To shorten your code you may use the following inside `change` handler: `$(".complaint").not(this).prop({ required : false, disabled : true }).closest("li").toggle(this.value.length == 0);`.

Comment: The only problem with that is it does not change the .prop({ required : false, disabled : true }) to the opposite when the select is changed to the empty string value

Comment: @Codded Ah yes.. But you may use the same logic to set true or false: `var flag = this.value.length == 0; $(".complaint").not(this).prop({ required : flag, disabled : !flag }).closest("li").toggle(flag);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('select')
        .not(this)
        .prop({ disabled: true, required: false })
        .css({ background: '#e8e8e8' });
});
```